# How to dismiss a Dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, android-softkeyboard, dismiss

I have problem with dismissing a Dialog.
I have two cases:
1. Insert a presence without info (so the soft Keyboard doesn't appear, when I click on the editText).
2. Insert a presence with info.

```
private Dialog newPresenceUser;
newPresenceUser= new Dialog(activity);
ImageView addPresenceButton=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_pres);
addPresenceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CardView send;
            final Spinner tipo;
            final EditText info;
            final ImageButton exit;

            newPresenceUser.setContentView(R.layout.new_presenza);
            exit=(ImageButton)newPresenceUser.findViewById(R.id.exit_event_button);
            tipo=(Spinner) newPresenceUser.findViewById(R.id.spinner_tipo);
            send=(CardView) newPresenceUser.findViewById(R.id.event_insert);
            info=(EditText)newPresenceUser.findViewById(R.id.info_presenza);
            exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    newPresenceUser.dismiss();
                }
            });

            send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //newPresenceUser.cancel();
                    String infoAgg=info.getText().toString();

                    try {

                        new GestorePresenza().inserisciPresenza(activity,user,tipo.getSelectedItem().toString(),infoAgg,lstCont.get(i).getUid(),(View)viewGroup.getParent(),newPresenceUser);

                        newPresenceUser.dismiss();

                    } catch (ParseException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

            newPresenceUser.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

            newPresenceUser.show();
        }
    });
```

So the problem is, when I click on the *editText* - the *softKeyboard* appears.
If I insert the presence without click on the *editText*, it works with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to dismiss dialog. First check dialog showing if dialog showing then you can dismiss otherwise may be your app was crashed.

```
  if(newPresenceUser!=null && 
        newPresenceUser.isShowing())
   {
          newPresenceUser.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, i resolve. the problem was, i don't know why , the dialog will generated two times if i clicked on the editText so the first reference i passed is not valid.